# MVC model casting in partial view, f__AnonymousType6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to cast a model going into a partial view?

```
@Html.Partial(Model.Partial, new { model =
((WarningPopupModel)CommonData.NotificationPopup.PopupModel) })
```

Here PopupModel is of type object but holds an instance of WarningPopupModel, when I try this is the error I get

```
Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
'<>f__AnonymousType6`1[EmployeeKiosk.Models.WarningPopupModel]', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type
'EmployeeKiosk.Models.WarningPopupModel'.
```

So really I need to understand the 'f__AnonymousType6' part and know what kind of flexibility I have here

Background.

I want to create a popup in the view depending on some business logic, so ultimately the controller will pass back the name of the view (or it could be a token) together with some model.

In the view I just need some way of being able to switch between the partial views that appear, the partial views will be Kendo popups

thanks

Comment: The "Anonymous Type" part refers to this: `new { ... }` - you're passing in an anonymous object which has your model in it as a property called `model`. You probably want to just pass in `(WarningPopupModel)CommonData.NotificationPopup.PopupModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure that you should just be able to change it to;

```
@Html.Partial(Model.Partial, (WarningPopupModel)CommonData.NotificationPopup.PopupModel);
```

Without the `new { model = ... }` part.

Comment: Argh! Simple as that, yep that worked. I'll accept it as the answer in 11 minutes :-)

Comment: It is one of those MVC things which everyone ends up doing once! :)